# What is most efficient way to write this webflux code?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have this code . In method A , I have to call b.subcribe(). without it method B will not executed. what is efficient way to call it without using subscibe. I feel like subcribe is not right way here

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        Mono<Integer> a = t.A();

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
        a.subscribe(a1-> System.out.println(a1));
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);

    }

     Mono<Integer> A(){
         Mono<Integer> integerMono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

             System.out.println("Hello");
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             return 1;
         });


         Mono<Integer> b = integerMono.flatMap(this::B);

         b.subscribe();

         return integerMono;
     }

    Mono<Integer> B(int a ){
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("B method");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return a * 100;
        });

    }
```

I have found another way to avoid subscribe. Not sure it is the best way

```
Mono<Integer> A(){
         Mono<Integer> integerMono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

             System.out.println("Hello");
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             return 1;
         });

         
         return integerMono.flatMap(
                 a -> {
                     return this.B(a).map(x->a);
                 }
         );
     }
```

Comment: Just remove the line `b.subscribe()`

Comment: method B will never be called then

Comment: `b.then(integerMono)`

Comment: method A  will be called 2 times which is very bad by using b.then(interMono)

Answer (score 0):

you code doesn't do anything, so when you are saying as "efficient as possible" its impossible to answer.

You should not `subscribe` unless you are the final consumer. You are sleeping all over the places, which means you are blocking threads witch should not be done either in webflux.

So if you want an actual solution, you should give us the actual problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Test t = new Test();
    Mono<Integer> a = t.A();

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    a.subscribe(a1-> System.out.println(a1));
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
}

public static class Test {

     Mono<Integer> A(){
         Mono<Integer> integerMono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

             System.out.println("Hello");
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             return 1;
         });

         // Here just return
         return integerMono.flatMap(this::B);
     }

    Mono<Integer> B(int a ){
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("B method");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return a * 100;
        });
    }
}
```

There is nothing to make more efficient... you are literally calling a function which in turn calls a function.